# Json.NET parse array in object

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I'm having an extremely difficult time parsing multiple arrays out of an array, embedded in several object in JSON.

Basically the json looks like

```
{
 took:8,
 success:true,
 items:[
  keywords:{...},
  mainInfo:{
    name:'...',
    expDate:'...',
    targetCities:[...],
    targetStates:[...]
  },
  additionalInfo:{
    skills:[],
    homeTime:''
  }
}
```

My C# looks like:

```
public class Job{
  public string name{get;set;}
  public List<string> targetCities{get;set;}
  public List<string> targetStates{get;set;}
  public List<string> skills{get;set;}
  public string homeTime{get;set;}
}
public class Jobs{
  private JObject o;
  private List<Job> jobs;
  public Jobs(string json){
    this.o=JObject.Parse(json);
  }
  public List<Job> toList(){
    List<JObject> allJobs=o["items"].Select(t => (JObject)t).ToList();
    foreach(JObject i in allJobs){
      Job j=new Job();
      j.name=(string)i["mainInfo"]["name"];
      j.targetCities=i["mainInfo"]["targetCities"].Select(t =>(string)t).ToList();
      j.targetStates=i["mainInfo"]["targetStates"].Select(t =>(string)t).ToList();
      j.expDate=(string)i["mainInfo"]["expDate"]
      j.skills=i["additionalInfo"]["skills"].Select(t =>(string)t).ToList();
      j.homeTime=(string)i["additionalInfo"]["homeTime"];
      this.jobs.Add(j); //ERROR
    }
    return this.jobs;
}
```

The error is a `Null Reference Exception`, with the info `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, however it seems that this error jumps around almost unpredictably as I try and change my code to fix the bug.

I am by no means a C# or .NET expert. I had dealt with the language in the past, but I personally do not like it. So forgive me for any stupid error I may have made.

### ADDITION:

I'm basically stepping through all the items and trying to create a `Job` object from each item using the data accordingly.

Comment: How is JObject defined?

Comment: It's a JSON.net object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `jobs` field, `private List<Job> jobs;`
You don't need this private field if you alway generate the jobs list. Use a local variable.

```
public List<Job> toList()
        {
            jobs = new List<Job>(); //add this line
            List<JObject> allJobs = o["items"].Select(t => (JObject)t).ToList();
            foreach (JObject i in allJobs)
            {
                Job j = new Job();
                j.name = (string)i["mainInfo"]["name"];
                j.targetCities = i["mainInfo"]["targetCities"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
                j.targetStates = i["mainInfo"]["targetStates"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
                j.expDate = (string)i["mainInfo"]["expDate"];
                j.skills = i["additionalInfo"]["skills"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
                j.homeTime = (string)i["additionalInfo"]["homeTime"];
                this.jobs.Add(j); 
            }
            return this.jobs;
        }
```

Comment: I actually noticed this a bit ago. I also pulled jobs into the scope of the toList method rather than having it as a property. The problem actually happened to be that the developer who wrote the API spelled a bunch of `keys` wrong in the JSON while in the API documentation they are spelled correctly.

Comment: Also the json was missing some brackets, I wanted to test and could not parse it. Anyway the error was coming from that variable.

Comment: the json provided was just simple mock-up. The json that I was dealing with was about 50x larger than the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may define allJobs first

```
List<JObject> allJobs = new List<JObject>();
allJobs=o["items"].Select(t => (JObject)t).ToList();
```

Comment: `.ToList()` creates and assigns a List object.

Comment: Have you tried my code? If you don't define the instance, there is no memory allocated.

Comment: The instance is defined by the ToList method, however.

Comment: My jobs object, however, was never initialized. I'll give you +1 for bringing the thought to the table.